# Netziv's drasha on purim

Tags: jewish-books, haamek-davar

The Netziv in [Ha'ameik She'eilah](https://www.sefaria.org/Haamek_Sheilah_on_Sheiltot_d%27Rav_Achai_Gaon.26.11.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) refers to his drasha for Purim. What is the name of the sefer with the Netziv's drashos and where can I find it (preferably online)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Netziv is referring to R. Achai Gaon's *derashah* on Purim (and his own commentary thereon).

This is the last piece of the She'iltot on Sefer Shemot which is commonly printed without a reference number and instead simply entitled לפורים (although it can also be referred to as She'ilta 67). See e.g. [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39101&st=&pgnum=224).

(By the way, the piece of Ha'amek She'elah to which you linked refers to what Netziv wrote on דרשה דפורים אות ב'‏. In my humble opinion this is a misprint; it should say אות ג'‏.)

Comment: Thanks. I sent feedback to sefaria about the reference.

Comment: I don’t think it’s Sefaria’s fault. It seems to appear that way in printed editions as well

Comment: Ok, but why not let them fix it. They want feedback to improve their website.

Comment: I agree. It's definitely worthwhile submitting feedback